# How to delete a row from sqlite table in recycler view items in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a row in sqlite database from recyclerview adapter. Based on the position of the adapter, I am deleting my row in sqlite like this :

```
helper = new DBHelper(v.getContext());
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
//statement = database.compileStatement("update result set ANS =? where SNO ='" + pos + "'");
// statement = database.compileStatement("delete result where SNO ='" + pos + "'");
//statement.bindString(1, ANS);
// statement.executeInsert();
database.delete("result",
"SNO = ? ",
new String[]{Integer.toString(pos)});
Log.d("pos", "" + pos);
//  helper.Delete(pos);
database.close();
```

but it is not deleting in my table, and I am not getting any error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you pass right pos ?? and what your log.d value

Answer (score 3):

```
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int l;
    l = db.delete("result", SNO = ? " , new String[]{pos+1});
    if (l > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Removed "+(pos+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    db.close();
```

Here you have pass "pos" so you have not passed right SNO(pos).

Please check SNO is passes on delete query

Comment: now got my problem whats happening , in listview its starts from 0 and in databse thats starts from 1 and when i delete database through at first i wll delete for firs t element after that in database there is no such row ..but    listview alwas starts from 0 so it wont delete my database .. what i can do it for that?

Comment: you use pos+1 instead of pos

Comment: then how you get pos?

Comment: listview always starts 0 or 1(pos+1) but if i delete db we wont get from 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this method ,

```
   public int deleteItem(String id) {

    open();
    int b = 0;
    try {

        b = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_POST_ITEMS, TAG_PLUS + " = '" + id + "'", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    close();
    return b;
}
```

call this by using this sentence,

```
   holder.img_plus.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dbhelper.deleteItem((chatMessageList.get((int) v.getTag()).getListid()));
                    chatMessageList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```